# Conditional labeling

Tags: qgis, labeling, sql

I would like to write a SQL query with a condition inside of it.

I got one table with two columns named "i" and "i_o".

What I want is to use the values of "i" for labeling my entities BUT if the value of "i" is "other" then it would show the value of "i_o" instead  of "i" for the same row.

I'm a noob in SQL so I don't really know of to get that working.

Comment: Can you please provide the code you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

A solution using a case

```sql
SELECT CASE
  WHEN i = 'other' THEN i_o
  ELSE i
END as i
FROM your_table
```

You can mostly do the same without any SQL using QGIS expressions for labeling if using Desktop GIS like QGIS but I do not know your usage context (web or desktop, software used,...)